# When is it a good idea to test a build with both clang and gcc?

Tags: gcc, clang

I am peeking through the code of [torsocks](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git/tree/.travis.yml?id=47b10b686e8e94fe0a2096135d4d9b195afb5267) where as you'll notice, the .travis.yml file instructs Travis CI to test against both clang *and* gcc.

```
compiler:
  - clang
  - gcc
```

I'm still learning and this caught my attention. Why both? Why not just one or the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two compilers have different quirks, and different levels of support for the various C and C++ standards. Code that compiles for one may trigger an error on the other. If you want folks to be able to build your software using either compiler, you have to test that you've accomodated for the differences between the compilers.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was pretty obvious in retrospect haha.

Comment: It also effectively prevents using compiler-specific features that would limit portability.

Comment: @AlexReinking actually you can still take advantage of compiler specific features, but you have to have a more elaborate build, and you may need to use the preprocessor to support alternative blocks of code for each compiler.